# Why my cocos2D scene in my UIView not responding?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I have 2 `UIViewController`s that implement cocos2d scene in every `UIViewController`. If the user taps the "Page2" button, it will change to second view controller. If the user taps the "Back" button in the second view controller it will change to first view controller.

This is my "Page2" button code:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];

p2 = [[Page2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page2ViewController" bundle:nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Page2" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.view addSubview:p2.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

After this, page 2 is still responding with cocos2d scene. If I push the "Back" button, my cocos2d scene will not respond but it gives no error, no warning, no messages at all. I've tried to put `NSLog` in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` but that's not passed my code. This is my "Back" button code:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Back to Home" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `end` on CCDirector. Instead, use `stopAnimation` and `startAnimation` to temporarily suspend Cocos2D. I'm not sure if this will help with your problem though, but it might.

Comment: If I dont put end on CCDirector it will return error because "You can't run an scene if another scene is running". I setup cocos2d scene every UIViewController. Any other ideas??Thanks

Comment: Yup, you need to use replaceScene instead of runWithScene. RunWithScene can only be used for loading the very first scene.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some use:

E.g., On first button click you move to `SecondScene`:

```
-(void)buttonClicked_color:(id)sender
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:[SecondScene node]]];
}
```

and when in `SecondScene` and want to go back to `FirstScene`:

```
-(void)buttonClicked_alpha:(id)sender
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:[FirstScene node]]];
}
```